# What is the last segment of a JBoss Vault?

Tags: jboss

In a JBoss Vault expression, what is the meaning of the last (numerical) segment?

```
VAULT::vaultBlock::attributeName::1
```

And what is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last segment of a JBoss Vault expression was used to put the shared key, but it is no longer needed. By default vault.bat puts 1.

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4238?focusedCommentId=13031690&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13031690